# Magento custom ajax cart. Shopping rule not applying

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, cart

I am using a custom ajax cart module where if a coupon is applied to that cart, a free gift item will add automatically to cart. The product is added to quote table without issues. There is a shopping rule defined for that free gift product, if it is in the cart 50% discount will be aplicable to cart subtotal.

But discount is not appliying.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
->load($productId);

$product->addCustomOption('freegift_with_code',1);

$product->setPrice(0);

$request = array('product'=>$product->getId(),'qty'=>1,'freegift_with_code'=>1,'freegift_coupon_code'=>$couponCode,'rule_id'=>$rule->getId(),'free-gift'=>true);

$cart->addProduct($product,$request);

$cart->save();

$this->_getQuote()->setFreeCouponCode(serialize($appliedCode))->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals()->save();
```